# How to have version in WAR filename, but not require it in the URL when deployed in Tomcat

Tags: maven, tomcat, maven-3, tomcat9, maven-war-plugin

I want to version my WAR to make DevOps lives easier, i.e.: *foo-3.2.0.war*. In *pom.xml*, I have:

```
<build>
  <finalName>foo</finalName>
```

but also

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${maven-war-plugin.version}</version>
  <configuration>
    <warName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</warName>
```

that imparts the current version in *pom.xml* to the WAR filename. So far, so good.

The problem becomes that the version is required in the URL when deployed to Tomcat. I want my application accessed thus: `http://hostname:port/foo` and not `http://hostname:port/foo-3.2.0` (etc.) because I'd have to annoy my consumer with the version change.

Is it possible to work around this problem without just going back to an unversioned WAR file?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `${project.artifactId}##${project.version}` as naming scheme.

The part after `##` will not be part of the context name (cf. [parallel deployment](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Parallel_deployment)).

Comment: Okay, resulting WAR-filename not handsome, but very workable. I think I can sell it. Thank you.

Comment: @rus-bateman keep in mind that multiple version could be deployed and users will access old versions until their session expires. Then the new one will be served for those.